# ServiceStack (Self-hosted) - running a curl from Windows console

Tags: servicestack

I am trying to run a curl command from Windows console. (eg curl.exe http://localhost:8087/ServiceStackRequest)

However, the information returned provides me with a "Error 401.2 Unauthorized".
... " [ Logon Method: Not yet determined. Logon user: Not yet determined".

In IIS, I have enabled
 - AppPool: given access to the specific user who has got access
 - Service (Site): enabled pass-through authentication with said user.

However, the authentication details are not being passed when running the command. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Ok got it working.

In IIS, 
(i) disabled Windows authentication
(ii) enabled anonymous authentication